# Как дождаться выполнения всех асинхронных операций?

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
validateAndUpdate = async validationData => {
    let valid = true;

    await validationData.forEach(async ({
        value,
        validationOkCb,
        validationErrCb,
        validator
    }) => {
        let res = await validator(value);

        if(!res.length)
            validationOkCb() 
        else{
            valid = false
            validationErrCb(res)
        } 
    })

    return valid;
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы выполнялись все асинхронные операции до возврата из функции?

Comment: А `validator` у вас что возвращает? Можете добавить код хотя бы одного `validator`.

Comment: Хм, а вы посмотрите в документации что возвращает forEach. Тогда вопрос почему await ничего не ждёт отпадёт сам собой.